# the region that has a flourishing mining industry know as,,,

Tags: restrictive-clauses, dangling-modifier

a. I was in the region that has a flourishing mining industry known as Boyer.

In the above sentence, could 'known as Boyer' modify 'the region'?

Comment: No source given in question.  Is this from a text book? Is it meant to illustrate some point in English?

Answer (score 1):

It would have to.  Pragmatically "Boyer" is a proper noun and a geographical name.  Industries don't have names like "Boyer", so the only place mentioned is the "region".  And so "known as Boyer" must modify "region".

But well-phrased sentences avoid long gaps between nouns and phrases that modify them. This could be rephrased, perhaps into two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I add to what @James K has said.

> a. I was in the region that has a flourishing mining industry known as Boyer.

*known as Boyer* is placed closer to *industry* than *region* and hence could be interpreted as modifying *industry*.

However, as Boyer starts with capital letter, it should be a place, and hence *known as Boyer* should be modifying *region*.

This shows that the sentence has a misplaced modifier problem.

You could consider

> a1. I was in the region Boyer that/which has a flourishing mining industry.
> or
> a2. I was in the region Boyer, which has a flourishing mining industry.

We could use a2 if readers can already identify the place by the name but use a1 if we need this additional identification.